# Angular binding data source from template to function issue

Tags: angular, binding

I have a table, that get data for dropdown from ts file function. 
part of html:

```
      <ng-container matColumnDef="from">
        <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>From</th>
...
          <form *ngIf="element.editable" [formGroup]="element">
            <ng-select
              class="cell"
              appendTo="body"
              [items]="getEventDates(element, true)"
              etc..
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="until">
        <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>Until</th>
...
              <form *ngIf="element.editable" [formGroup]="element">
                <ng-select
                  class="cell"
                  appendTo="body"
                  [items]="getEventDates(element, false)"
                  etc...
      </ng-container>
```

The function should once filter large data for passed element and give it to dropdown:

```
  getEventDates(element: MachineTrackHistoryFormGroup, isFromColumn: boolean | null): IMachineEventDateObject[] {
       console.log('getEventDates')
        return this.eventDates
          .filter(x => x.type == element.record.type &&
                        isFromColumn ? x.from <= element.record.output.from : x.from >= element.record.input?.from)
    }
  }
```

But if I open a dropdown and scroll it I see in the console, that instead of 2 calls of getEventDates, there are hundreds of calls of it. 
What are the ways to resolve this issue? I want just once to call getEventDates function and get data for the needed dropdown, that depends on a passed element.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see hundreds of console logs because the method `getEventDates` gets executed on every change detection cycle. It's usually recommended to avoid binding methods in the template. Read [this](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496).

Instead you can create a property like `eventDates`, assign it the calculated value from `getEventDates`, and bind it to ng-select (`[items] = eventDates`).
You can call this method on the change event on `ng-select`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a getter function that has computed behavior (only executed if there is an update)

```
get filtredEventDates(){
 return this.eventDates
}
```

And filter data inside ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit(){
let selectedElement = ...;
this.eventDates = this.getEventDates(selectedElement, true)
}
```

Insite Html template

```
          [items]="filtredEventDates"
```

Comment: It's not possible to compute it in ngOnInit cuz the function should return filtered elements for different elements on the table and it depends on the user (he can select for editing any element that table has)

Comment: Try to use global variables for  selected element  and Its state edited or not.